# Inconsistency with Typescript Readonly type

Tags: typescript

I'm running into an inconsistency with the Typescript [Readonly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlyt) that I don't understand.

<sub>Typescript v3.9.2 playground: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8BQyyIcAthAFzIDOYU2A3PgL776iSyIoDyARgCs8hZHChQqGbAG0AukyJhMILJOVYmrfAgD2IWslIBPAILjkVAEoQ4AEz0AbIwB4pKuQD5kAXmTTcJORUAORwwcwANHiBlMjBfOHy2noGxm44Vjb2IE6u6l6+AWSxwTA6OuFMyfpghkb8AlQNPsKK6lRp6hEiYhJ1ZlBRAPRDaJjUyEpQOgDuE3DIuqQADsAOKNDTUCxAA)</sub>

```
interface Thing {
  name: string;
}

interface Obj {
  arr: Thing[];
  thing: Thing;
}

const myArr : Readonly<Thing[]> = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}];
const myThing : Readonly<Thing> = {name: 'foo'};

const myObj: Obj = {
  thing: myThing,
  arr: myArr, // This throws a compile error
}
```

The above code gives me the following compile error:

```
The type 'readonly Thing[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Thing[]'.(4104)
```

That error makes sense, I'm assigning a readonly array to a mutable array type.

What I don't understand is why I don't get a similar error for the `thing` prop of `myObj`.

I would expect that assigning a `Readonly<Thing>` to a prop that expects a `<Thing>` to also be illegal?

Thanks all!

Comment: I wrote an ESLint rule to prevent this scenario: https://github.com/danielnixon/eslint-plugin-total-functions#total-functionsno-unsafe-assignment

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The fact that this does not result in an error:

```
const thing: Thing = myThing; // no error
```

is a known issue with `readonly` and is currently working as intended, as per [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6532#issuecomment-174356151) on the pull request that implemented `readonly`, [microsoft/TypeScript#6532](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6532):

> In order to ensure backwards compatibility, the `readonly` modifier doesn't affect subtype and assignability type relationships of the containing type (but of course it affects assignments to individual properties).

It was too much of a breaking change to strictly enforce `readonly` because so much existing TypeScript code used type definitions with no mention of `readonly`, and it's not possible to know whether to treat that existing code as mutable or read-only.  And since there's no `mutable` keyword, there's no way for the compiler to tell the difference between legacy properties which may or may not be readonly from new properties that are intended to be mutable:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string; // <-- is this a legacy readonly property or a new mutable one?
}
```

The compiler therefore treats all non-`readonly`-annotated properties as "possibly `readonly`" and allows assignment between them.  It's a compromise.

There's an open suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#13347](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347) to introduce a compiler flag or some other mechanism to more strictly enforce `readonly`, but it's been around for a long time and it's not clear whether or not this will ever happen.

---

On the other hand, the fact this the following *does* result in an error,

```
const arr: Thing[] = myArr; // error!
```

*actually has nothing to do with `readonly` properties*, despite the (somewhat misleading, in my opinion) error message:

```
// The type 'readonly Thing[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Thing[]'
```

It's because `readonly Thing[]` is interpreted as `ReadonlyArray<Thing>` via [`readonly` array/tuple syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#a-new-syntax-for-readonlyarray), and that happens with `Readonly<T>` because a [`readonly` mapped type with array properties are made into `ReadonlyArray` properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-mapped-type-modifiers-and-readonly-arrays).

It's true that the index signature on `ReadonlyArray<T>` is `readonly` and the one on `Array<T>` is not.  But the important difference is that `ReadonlyArray<T>`'s type definition is missing the methods of `Array<T>` that are known to modify the array.  Like `push()`, for example:

```
myArr.push({ name: "" }); // error! push does not exist on readonly Thing[];
arr.push({ name: "" }); // okay
```

You can't assign a `ReadonlyArray<T>` to an `Array<T>` because the former's type definition is missing some methods that are required in the latter's type definition. They're just not type compatible. That's it.

It used to be that when you tried to make such an assignment, you got an error that actually did explain this; but it was quite daunting.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30839](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30839) for more information.  The old error was something like:

```
// Type 'readonly Thing[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Thing[]`:
//   pop, push, reverse, shift, and 6 more.
```

So it was changed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30016](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30916) to the error message shown above that mentions `readonly`.

---

Okay, hope that explains the difference between those two cases.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8BQyyIcAthAFzIDOYU2A3PgL75sID2ItypAnhmxUAShDgATLgBs+AHkEgsAPmQBePMTKVkAchgcOO5MyaduYZGEyKqCnOv52GyAPQviHZNCgcobfGY8-ACCUFAiYpIgMvLWWADaALoq6vG4muRUOnBGzAA0GiSZugBGuYmmXDxwYbZxSWq8fKFQzm5eYb4AhPjtGChgfAAOKDpQkdJ8aPWJRsDUuuMSk0ZwIOLICGsgHBYlKHDU1MBYIBAbYJ5WKKQArmBwJVIDw6N2STpsIWEAdEO31HQAAp0kVtAAicHGACUbXc3m6yH+gOQkggCx2FggAA95hYuMgllEZNNsEkmDUoH8AcDQVoqJCYXDkBwANZwKZAA)

Comment: This is an excellent and incredibly thorough answer, thank you so much! All the context links were especially helpful, it's cool to see how the language has evolved over time :)

Comment: quick note, the link to the comment on the `readonly` pull request is wrong. I think it should be [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6532#issuecomment-174356151)